# Using RegionPlot to remove shell surface portions

Tags: plotting

```
gam = 0; b = 1;
a = 2;
p20 = ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[u], a Sin[u] Cos[gam] + b v Sin[gam], 
    b v}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -8, 8}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[.3]}];
a = 1.5;
p15 = ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[u], a Sin[u] Cos[gam] + b v Sin[gam], 
    b v}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -8, 8},
   PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[.3]}];
a = 1.0;
p10 = ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[u], a Sin[u] Cos[gam] + b v Sin[gam], 
    b v}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -8, 8}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[.3]}];
a = 0.5;
p05 = ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[u], a Sin[u] Cos[gam] + b v Sin[gam], 
    b v}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -8, 8}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Opacity[.3]}];
a = 4;
cyl = ParametricPlot3D[{a Sin[u] Cos[gam] + b v Sin[gam] - 4, b v, 
   a Cos[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -3, 3}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Purple, Opacity[.6]}]
Show[{p20, p15, p10, p05, cyl}, PlotRange -> All]
```

How to remove ( so as not to be seen in display) the cut tubular portions lying inside bigger purple cylinder? There may a single code line to see all the shell assembly intersections without repetition. I don't seem to get it always right..Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Append[Table[
  ConditionalExpression[{a Cos[u], a Sin[u] Cos[gam] + b v Sin[gam], b v}, 
   (a Cos[u] + 4)^2 + (b v)^2 >= 16], {a, {2, 1.5, 1., .5}}],
  ConditionalExpression[{4 Sin[u] Cos[gam] + b v Sin[gam] - 4, b v, 4 Cos[u]},
    -3 <= v <= 3]]], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -8, 8}, 
 PlotStyle -> Append[Table[Opacity[.3, Yellow], {4}], Opacity[.6, Purple]], 
 PlotRange -> All,  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Mesh -> None ]
```

[image]

**Update:** Highlighting the boundaries:

```
plots = Table[ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[u], a Sin[u] Cos[gam] + b v Sin[gam], b v}, 
   {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -8, 8}, 
   PlotStyle -> Opacity[.2, Yellow], Mesh -> None, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   RegionFunction -> ((a Cos[#4] + 4)^2 + (b #5)^2 >= 16 &)], 
 {a, {2, 1.5, 1., .5}}];

boundaries = Table[ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[u], a Sin[u] Cos[gam] + b v Sin[gam], b v}, 
   {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -8, 8}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {(a Cos[#4] + 4)^2 + (b #5)^2 - 16 &}, 
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], PlotStyle -> None], 
 {a, {2, 1.5, 1., .5}}] /. Line -> ({Red, Tube[#, .1]} &);

cyl = ParametricPlot3D[{4 Sin[u] Cos[gam] + b v Sin[gam] - 4, b v, 4 Cos[u]}, 
  {u, 0, 2 Pi}, {v, -3, 3}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.6, Purple]];

Show[plots, boundaries, cyl, PlotRange -> All
```

[image]

Comment: Can we draw intersecting ovals with more contrasting lines?

Comment: @Narasimham, maybe playing with  `BoundaryStyle` settings may give what you are asking, but i have not been able make it work in version 9.

Answer (score 0):

using region tools.

```
c1[r_] := 
  ImplicitRegion[
   x^2 + y^2 == r^2 , {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -8, 8}}];
c2 = ImplicitRegion[(x - 2)^2 + z^2 == 
   3^2 , {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -8, 8}}]
c2s = ImplicitRegion[(x - 2)^2 + z^2 < 
   3^2 , {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -8, 8}}]
Show[{
  DiscretizeRegion[c2, 
   MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> {Opacity[.5], Purple}}],
  Table[
   {DiscretizeRegion[RegionDifference[c1[r], c2s], 
     MeshCellStyle -> {{2, All} -> {Opacity[.5], Orange}}], 
    DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[c1[r], c2], 
     MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> {Thickness[.01], Red}}]}, {r, {1, 
     1.5, 2}}]}]
```

[image] [image]

( note MeshCellStyle here needs v 11 )